# Locating correct element when class names are the same (Selenium)

Tags: selenium

There are two toggle buttons with exact same class names, so the way i could only manage to locate the relevant one is to locate list of those elements and choose the correct index which is not really sufficient as the order can possibly change.

```
@FindBy(css = ".switch.toggle-switch")
public List<WebElement> toggleList;

 private void clickOnAgreeWithTermsToggle(){
        signUpForm.toggleList.get(1).click();
    }
```

Could somebody kindly let me know how to proceed is such cases, thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible if these two buttons are completly same, but that should not be the case.

Maybe you can use the text from your HTML if it is related to the button.

@FindBy(css = ".toggle-switch-text"))
public List toggleList;

signUpForm.toggleList.get(1).getText() == "Remember me"